# Wordpress Player Profiles + PHP

Tags: php

I'm totally new to website programming..

I am making a website for my Counter Strike Server.  I want people to be able to create profiles. And these profiles have to display custom stats from their game performance.. the stats come from a mysql data base.

Possible?
Should i use phpbb?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you are talking about phpbb and bbpress?
The actual problem does not involve forum software, does it?

Something that I found is following:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates

This explains how to create your player profiles. Create a author.php in your theme folder and make it display any author related information you want. You can also run mysql queries and format the results properly to display your gaming stats.

As Ahmad mentioned, it is reasonable to store the user_id of your gamestats mysql table in wordpress user meta data.

Comment: Agreed, there's no reason whatsoever for phpbb or bbpress to be involved here, those are forum software which is completely different. The only plugin worth mentioning here is BuddyPress, but that's unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should edit the theme's profile.php file,you could get the custom stats either by directly accessing the database or by a creating a web service,but you should store the original user id from the mysql table in a user meta 
so you could use it in queries or web service

Answer (score 0):

You can use phpbb to do this work but if you want to do this in wordpress then use bbpress plugin.

Comment: Isn't WordPress easier for starters?

Comment: Yes it is easier.